# How to pause updates until all changes are done?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Sheet script that modifies column widths, hides/undhides columns, and
hides/unhides rows.

I'd like the sheet to update once after all changes are done.
Currently, it's like animation - each change is reflected dynamically. 
The constant redraw is slow.

Any idea how to make it "pause" until all updates are done, then do one 'refresh' to see all changes at once?

-AC

Comment: Use batch methods, aka better code. You don't show any code, so that's the only suggestion we can give. There's no `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` for Apps Script.